# How can I solve this simple search query for php MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table (table1) with following fields...

id, title, description, detail, category, status

What I am trying to do is searching these fields with regular php search query... My query for now is...

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE title LIKE '%$q%' OR description LIKE '%$q%' OR detail LIKE '%$q%' AND category='$cateid' AND status='1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Where `$q` is my search string, `$cateid` is my category id and status is On/Off (Active/Inactive)

Now if get results with this query I got 5 results while I have query string = foo and it only exists in one entry not 5... And also it is showing me the rows with status='0' 
When I change my query to

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE title LIKE '%$q%' AND category='$cateid' AND status='1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
```

It gives me correct results... 
But I also want to match my query string to description and detail fields respectively. 
Please help me out.

Comment: Use braces. `AND` has precedence over `OR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put parentheses () around all the OR conditions

```
SELECT * FROM table1
  WHERE (title LIKE '%$q%' OR description LIKE '%$q%' OR detail LIKE '%$q%')
    AND category='$cateid' AND status='1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the query you need:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE
    (title LIKE '%$q%' OR detail LIKE '%$q%')
    AND category='$cateid' AND status='1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
```